# ordered list in C returning just one node (head overwritten)

Tags: c, list, pointers, nodes, dynamic-allocation

I'm trying to create an ordered list in C, given a specific prototype:

```
int insertInOrder (list_t list, char *surname, char *name);
```

The function should insert all nodes in the correct position (alphabetically ordered by surname first, name then - compared in function
 **comparison**) and return 1 if the insertion went through, 0 if the node is a duplicate.

**comparison** returns 1 if the first parameter is greater then the second, -1 if it is lesser and 0 if the two parameters are equal.
I defined:

```
typedef struct list *list_t;

typedef struct node *link;

struct node{
    char *name;
    char *surname;
    link next;
};

struct list{
    link head;
};
```

This is my function:

```
int insertInOrder (list_t list, char *cognome, char *nome){
    link t = list->head;
    link p;

    link x = malloc(sizeof(*x));
    x->name = malloc(strlen(name)*sizeof(char));
    x->name = name;
    x->surname = malloc(strlen(surname)*sizeof(char));
    x->surname = surname;
    x->next = NULL;


    if(list->head == NULL){
        list->head = x;
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        while(t!=NULL){
            if(comparison(t,x)<0){
                p = t;
                t = t->next;
            }
            else if(comparison(t,x)>0){
                if(t == list->head){
                    x->next = list->head;
                    list->head = x;
                    return 1;
                }
                else{
                    p->next = x;
                    x->next = t;
                    return 1;
               }
            }
            else if(comparison(t,x)==0)
                return 0;
        }
        p->next = x;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

**t** is the pointer to the current node, **p** is the pointer to the previous one.

When I print the list, the head is overwritten (the new node replace the old one and the list appears as if it has just one node) and I can't understand why.

[console result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIQQZ.png)

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is the perfect time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: A couple of possible hints though: Don't forget that `char` strings in C are really called ***null-terminated** byte strings*. That *null-terminator* need space too. And think about what happens when you assign a pointer to another pointer (the effect could be seen quite easily if stepping through your code line by line in a debugger, watching the actual value of the pointer variable, i.e. where they point).

Comment: On an unrelated note, `sizeof(char)` is defined by the C specification to *always* be equal to `1`. Don't need it in your `malloc` calls.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm using CodeBlocks as IDE and I tried to debug, but it seems not working with pointers. I'll try to add a char for the null-terminated string but I don't think that's the problem… since the current node is allocated correctly.